# Operate and output inplace results

Tags: directory-structure

I have a shell function which operates in-folder (in my case, it looks for *.eps` files and convert them to pdf without blank borders). Let us abstract this by the below function:

```
function do_here() {
    echo $(pwd)
}
```

I look for an intelligent way to traverse directories and paths given root path `ROOT_PATH` and operate `do_here` on each tree leaf. There may be symbolic leaves, but this requirement seems a plus at this point.

The rationale seems to be

1. Traverse directories from `ROOT_PATH` with alias `to_path`;
2. run `cd $to_path`;
3. run `do_here`;
4. Go to step 2.

I do not know how to obtain the list the directory paths from step 1.

Comment: which shell is this? bash? zsh?

Comment: Side note: I hope `echo $(pwd)` is just an example and you [don't use it](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690) in your real shell code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller plain bash.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash also supports `**` for recursive globbing, provided `shopt -s globstar` is set. And you can get only directories if you suffix the glob with a `/`. Add `dotglob` so you don't miss directories with names starting with a dot.

So, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
do_here() {
    echo "working in $(pwd)...";
}
# cd ROOT_PATH
for d in **/; do (
    cd "$d"
    do_here
)
done
```

Note that there are some differences in how `**` works between the shells, namely with regard to following symlinks inside the directory tree. If the tree contains a link to another directory, at least some versions of Bash would follow it, possibly going outside the tree. (I'm not sure what you mean with "symbolic leaves", so I don't know if that's a problem.)

Comment: Great. This is the answer I look for. Here, take this upvote and a check.

Answer (score 1):

To get all directories, just as to get all files in a directory, you'd use *globbing*; then, you'd use a `for` loop to iterate through the result, and either start a subshell (`( commands in subshell )`) or `pushd`/`popd` the directories on a stack. E.g.:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
for directory in **/*(ND/) ; do
  print -r -u2 Working on ${directory}
  (             # do in subshell, so that `cd` doesn't affect
                # the next iteration
    cd -- "${directory}" && \
    do_here     # && : only if `cd` succeeded, do `do_here`
  ) || { 
         print -r -- "${directory} failed" >&2 | \
         logger -p user.err 
       }
done
```

let's take that apart

```bash
for directory in **/*(ND/) ; do
# ^ ^---+---^    ^  ^ ^^^  
# |     |        |  | ||\ *(/) extended glob: match directories
# |     |        |  | |\- *(N) extended glob: null glob, i.e., don't fail if
# |     |        |  | |                       nothing matches
# |     |        |  | \-- *(D) extended glob: include directories starting with 
# |     |        |  |                         ".", i.e., normally hidden dirs
# |     |        |  \---- * glob operator
# |     |        \------- **/ apply the following globbing recursively
# |     |
# |     \---------------- "loop variable": `directory` gets set to each result, 
# |                       consecutively
# |
# \---------------------- for {variable name} in {list-generating expression} :
#                         for loop
```

Comment: `for dir (**/*(ND/)) (print -ru2 Working in $dir; cd -- $dir && do_here || print -r -- $dir failed >&2 | logger -p user.err)` would be a more zsh-y (and reliable) way to write it.

Comment: May we bring this answer to some common terminal sense?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I keep forgetting you can absorb globbing options in the glob string. I'll adjust that. I'll be a bit honest, though: Print's `-u2` is a bit too magic for my taste. (and the "working on" wasn't supposed to end up on stderr)

Comment: Progress messages, prompts  and the like should go on stderr. They're not meant to be the *product* of your script. `print -u` is from ksh from the 80s. `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data. Or at least use `echo -E`

Comment: `tee /dev/stderr` is  wrong on Linux and cygwin at least. zsh does a `tee`ing internally when a fd is redirected more than once for output. See the `print >&2 | logger` in my suggested improvement.

Comment: I personally just like `print,echo foo |  tee /dev/stderr | somethingelse` becasue it's so explicit.

Comment: May we write something bash-y, please? I am a humble man.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto I thoroughly believe that you're a humble man, but I don't think bash is any humbler than zsh; as a matter of fact, on my system, the zsh package needs slightly less space than the bash package.