# Suppress log on "List folder" command with no directories

Tags: ls

**Shell**: Bash

**Reproduction steps**:

1. Make a folder `mkdir folder`
2. Change folder `cd folder`
3. List directories `ls -d */ -A`
4. Read log message `ls: cannot access '*/': No such file or directory`

**Question**

How to avoid seeing this message on title-given scenario?

**Expected output**:

Nothing echoed.

**Reason**:

It is because:

1. Suppress verbosity;
2. Avoid errors;
3. Attend the scenario.

Comment: I assume you want something different than "don't run `ls */` in empty directories"? What *do* you expect, and why?

Comment: In some shells, you could ask for empty wildcard matches to be nulled out (bash: shopt -s nullglob); is that an acceptable workaround? In that case, `ls` would then receive no arguments, only the options you've listed.

Comment: I edited my question for you.

Comment: Just be aware that you're "swimming upstream" a bit by requesting no output when there's an "error" (you've requested a listing of something that isn't there)

Comment: yeah, simply don't make a listing of an empty directory. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Oftentimes I try to do something stupid first: do not search more than 10 minutes on internet for my thoghtful request. In this case, I start from what I know, data structures and bare coding, which leads to some weird corner case. I try to treat the corner cases likewise. They work sometimes, othertimes not. '\\_o_/'

Comment: My first attempt was follow: 1. Write a function to list folders; 2. Go inside each folder; 3. List folders from there; 3. Go back on leaf-case; 4. repeat from step 2. It seems reasonable. But then they answered other question of mine, which left this request foolish: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729430/operate-and-output-inplace-results/729455#729455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about suppressing stderr?

```
ls -d */ -A 2> /dev/null
```